# Batch format changing in Libre Office

Tags: formatting, libreoffice-writer

I would like to change the formatting of some pre-formatted text in a document using Libre Office. For example, I want to change every paragraph with font Arial 12pt to Helvetica 11pt.

Doing this manually is hard since I have other paragraphs with different formatting.

Is that possible in Libre Office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a Find and Replace. In the Find and Replace dialog box, click the More Options button. With the cursor in the Search For box, click the Format button and enter the parameters of the format to be changed. With the cursor in the Replace With box enter the new format parameters, then do a Replace All.